# Android build failed with ionic and angular

Tags: angular, ionic-native

I'm trying to build an android app with ionic and Angular

but I have some problems that I can't find a solution

command : ionic cordova build android

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7s
> 1 actionable task: 1 executed
> Subproject Path: CordovaLib
> Subproject Path: app
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
> Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libsqlc-native-driver.so.

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> /Users/user/Desktop/nosrb-front-end/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/camera/CameraLauncher.java:40: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
> import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
> ^
> /Users/user/Desktop/nosrb-front-end/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/camera/CordovaUri.java:25: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
> import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
> ^
> /Users/user/Desktop/nosrb-front-end/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/camera/FileProvider.java:21: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
> public class FileProvider extends android.support.v4.content.FileProvider {}
> ^
> /Users/user/Desktop/nosrb-front-end/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/ionicframework/cordova/webview/IonicWebViewEngine.java:11: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
> import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
> ^
> /Users/user/Desktop/nosrb-front-end/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/ionicframework/cordova/webview/IonicWebViewEngine.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
> @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
> ^
> symbol:   class RequiresApi
> location: class com.ionicframework.cordova.webview.IonicWebViewEngine.ServerClient
> /Users/user/Desktop/nosrb-front-end/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/camera/CameraLauncher.java:303: error: cannot find symbol
> this.imageUri = new CordovaUri(FileProvider.getUriForFile(cordova.getActivity(),
> ^
> symbol:   method getUriForFile(androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity,java.lang.String,java.io.File)
> location: class org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider
> /Users/user/Desktop/nosrb-front-end/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/camera/CameraLauncher.java:801: error: cannot find symbol
> Uri tmpFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(cordova.getActivity(),
> ^
> symbol:   method getUriForFile(androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity,java.lang.String,java.io.File)
> location: class org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> Note: /Users/user/Desktop/nosrb-front-end/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/org/apache/cordova/file/AssetFilesystem.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> 7 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 22s
45 actionable tasks: 45 executed
Command failed with exit code 1: /Users/user/Desktop/nosrb-front-end/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/user/Desktop/nosrb-front-end/platforms/android/build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

Answer (score 0):

### Replace

```
public class FileProvider extends android.support.v4.content.FileProvider
```

### for this

```
public class FileProvider extends androidx.core.content.FileProvider
```